QField - Tracking fuction doesn't save feature when photo attached(Gallery)
Using QField 3.3.11
I have a line feature layer and a photo table (Gallery) connected using a relationship.

If i manually draw the line feature on map canvas and attach photos the changes will save correctly.
If i use tracking to create the line but dont attach a photo it will save correctly. i can then later edit it and save photos.
If i use tracking and attach a photo the attributes are saved to both tables (Line layer + Photo table) but the actual geometry is not recorded against the line feature.


Commit errors:
ERROR: 1 Feature(s) not added
Provider errors:
OGR error creating feature -6: failed to execute insert : UNIQUE constraint failed:
layer_relationship_xyz
Unbalanced call to leaveUpdateMode() w.r.t. enterUpdateMode()

For QField errors I strongly recommend reporting the issue on the project github: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues to get the attention of the devs.

I have created a issue: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/5610
